# How can I auto-title a plot with the R call that produced it?

Tags: r

R's plotting is great for data exploration, as it often has very intelligent defaults. For example, when plotting with a formula the labels for the plot axes are derived from the formula. In other words, the following two calls produce the same output:

```
plot(x~y)
plot(x~y, xlab="x", ylab="y")
```

Is there any way to get a similar "intelligent auto-title"?

For example, I would like to call

```
plot(x~y, main=<something>)
```

And produce the same output as calling

```
plot(x~y, main="plot(x~y)")
```

Where the `<something>` inserts the call used using some kind of introspection.

Is there a facility for doing this in R, either through some standard mechanism or an external package?

edit: One suggestion was to specify the formula as a string, and supply that as the argument to a `formula()` call as well as `main`. This is useful, but it misses out on parameters than can affect a plot, such as using subsets of data. To elaborate, I'd like

```
x<-c(1,2,3)
y<-c(1,2,3)
z<-c(0,0,1)
d<-data.frame(x,y,z)
plot(x~y, subset(d, z==0), main=<something>)
```

To have the same effect as

```
plot(x~y, subset(d, z==0), main="plot(x~y, subset(d, z==0))")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this can be done without writing a thin wrapper around `plot()`. The reason is that R evaluates "supplied arguments" in the evaluation frame of the calling function, in which there's no way to access the current function call ([see here for details](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation)).

By contrast, "default arguments" are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the function, from where introspection *is* possible.  Here are a couple of possibilities (differing just in whether you want "myPlot" or "plot" to appear in the title:

```
## Function that reports actual call to itself (i.e. 'myPlot()') in plot title.
myPlot <- function(x,...) {
    cl <- deparse(sys.call())
    plot(x, main=cl, ...)
}

## Function that 'lies' and says that plot() (rather than myPlot2()) called it.
myPlot2 <- function(x,...) {
    cl <- sys.call()
    cl[[1]] <- as.symbol("plot")
    cl <- deparse(cl)
    plot(x, main=cl, ...)
}

## Try them out
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
par(mfcol=c(1,2))
myPlot(x,y)
myPlot2(y~x)
```

Here's a more general solution:

```
plotCaller <- function(plotCall, ...) {
    main <- deparse(substitute(plotCall))
    main <- paste(main, collapse="\n")
    eval(as.call(c(as.list(substitute(plotCall)), main=main, ...)))
}

## Try _it_ out

plotCaller(hist(rnorm(9999), breaks=100, col="red"))

library(lattice)
plotCaller(xyplot(rnorm(10)~1:10, pch=16))

## plotCaller will also pass through additional arguments, so they take effect
## without being displayed
plotCaller(xyplot(rnorm(10)~1:10), pch=16)
```

deparse will attempt to break deparsed lines if they get too long (the default is 60 characters). When it does this, it returns a vector of strings. plot methods assume that 'main' is a single string, so the line `main <- paste(main, collapse='\n')` deals with this by concatenating all the strings returned by deparse, joining them using `\n`.

Here is an example of where this is necessary:

```
plotCaller(hist(rnorm(9999), breaks=100, col="red", xlab="a rather long label",
    ylab="yet another long label"))
```

Comment: Brilliant! I think the more general solution solves the problem quite nicely. It is basically the same as Greg Snows's myplot2, but I've chosen this one as I think it is easier to understand how it works.

Comment: @saffsd -- Cool ideas in the edits you've made. Thanks! Would you please include an example that shows where the `paste(main, collapse="\n")` might come into play?

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is!  Here ya go:

```
x = rnorm(100)
y = sin(x)

something = "y~x"

plot(formula(something),main=something)
```

[image]

Comment: Is `paste` really necessary?

Comment: You can edit it to get exactly what you want but you get the idea.

Comment: You can do it without the paste.

Comment: Thanks! This is good but not perfect, as I'd like to see the whole call - in particular, using lattice plots with subsets of data. I'll elaborate the example.

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of the functionality of `match.call`.  However that only really works when called inside of a function, not passed in as an argument.  You could create your wrapper function that would call `match.call` then pass everything else on to `plot` or use substitute to capture the call then modify it with the call before evaluating:

```
x <- runif(25)
y <- rnorm(25, x, .1)

myplot <- function(...) {
    tmp <- match.call()
    plot(..., main=deparse(tmp))
}

myplot( y~x )
myplot( y~x, xlim=c(-.25,1.25) )

## or

myplot2 <- function(FUN) {
    tmp1 <- substitute(FUN)
    tmp2 <- deparse(tmp1)
    tmp3 <- as.list(tmp1)
    tmp4 <- as.call(c(tmp3, main=tmp2))
    eval(tmp4)
}

myplot2( plot(y~x) )
myplot2( plot(y~x, xlim=c(-.25,1.25) ) )
```